# Solitaire cipher riddle

Tags: cipher

I am trying to solve this problem but with no clue of what it actually means. Only thing i know is that it is solitaire cipher hidden message/key.
[image]

Here is the content of the image:

> To: root@epiphyte2.net
>       From: rlw@epiphyte2.net
>       Subject: Server Key
>
> ```
> AZAXV HEFWV WOUWQ CFEMH KARAZ EJVNL
> CBFOV MMMBM SNHBA UGKZM BJGIE OWZWW
> WBYVL OZJLS UBIPD EYJXD GMBEY XSIKL
> NABQZ NWTNT MAKZB NSRYJ ZYAPS FJNGR
> DXNAF OAWHO
> ```

Comment: For a solitaire cipher, a keystream is needed to decode. Without having the keystream, we can't do anything.

Comment: Keystream could be inside the message. This is the information given.

Comment: No, the message is not the same thing as the keystream. Where did you find this?

Comment: @Deusovi It's possible that the challenge of the puzzle is to identify the keystream. Maybe it's somehow in the email header?

Comment: What's the source of this? (And I think I *have* found the keystream - or at least, how to generate it - but I'd like to know where this is from.)

Comment: https://twitter.com/NCCGroupInfosec/status/786108266321502209

Comment: Is this an ongoing competition?

Comment: It have got posted few months back.

Comment: Are you sure `key-and-locks` tag is correct?